# Hibernate in Eclipse Plugin Development Project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf-ecore

Presently I work in eclipse plugin development project. Here, there is a need to persist the domain objects. Can hibernate be used for Java persistency in the existing ecore based model classes? If yes, what are the challenges has to be taken into consideration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/cdo/

That's probably what are you looking for.